# How to run Kubeflow pipelines periodically?

Tags: pipeline, kubeflow

I have pipelines on Kubeflow pipelines can be run on the pipelines UI.

My pipelines should be executed at the specified time like crontab.

How can I execute the pipelines periodically?

Comment: NB: The cron format used in kubeflow includes seconds as the first entry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried scheduling pipelines yet, but hopefully this may help.

From the Kubeflow Pipelines UI, create an experiment for your pipeline. On the experiment page for your pipeline, there is an option to **Create recurring run**. Follow the instructions on that form to schedule runs for your pipeline.

Comment: Great! The recurring run works well as I wanted. Moreover, it's easy to use. Thank you.

Comment: NB: The cron format used in kubeflow includes seconds as the first entry!

Comment: Here's docs on the cron format: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron#hdr-CRON_Expression_Format